# How to make compressed rar or zip files of certain size in Linux command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, zip, archiving

On my Ubuntu machine, I'd like to create compressed archive files of 10mb size for Windows users. So that a 25MB `myfile` becomes something like:

```
myfile1.rar
myfile2.rar
myfile1.rar
```

I could not find any working example of that in rar tutorials on Linux like [here](https://linuxconfig.org/compress-file-or-directory-using-rar-archive-tool-on-linux-shell). And for zip, a command that I found

```
zip  -s 10m -r  myfile.zip  myfile
```

Create files that can not be unzipped (at least not on the same Ubuntu machine GUI)

So appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this help: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-split-zip-archive-into-multiple-blocks-of-a-specific-size

Comment: No, that page also suggest `zip -r -s 5m myfiles.zip example-dir/`. It compresses but I have difficulty extracting the files.

Comment: You have to recombine the zip files first; see the example towards the bottom of the page.

Comment: General note on Unix philosophy: many tools follow the "do one thing and do it well" rule. There are archivers that can pack a directory structure to a single file (e.g. `tar`); there are compressors that can compress this file (e.g. `gzip`). Zip (or Rar) is different, one program can act as both and more, provide redundancy, encrypting, splitting. Windows users may think it has to be this way. In Linux there are separate tools, no need to bloat an archiver with extra functionality. E.g. you can split a file with `split` and concatenate back with `cat`, *the type of the file doesn't matter*.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I don't mind using a command chain to achieve the intended result. Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: In general this can work in a pipe: `archiver | compressor | split -b 10m`. After placing  the files generated by `split` (`xaa`, `xab`, …) in an empty directory, the other person should do `cat x* | decompressor | dearchiver`. I don't know how well `zip` works in a pipe, especially as decompressor+dearchiver *in Windows*; I don't know the equivalent of `cat x*` in Windows. Without zip you can `split -b 10m myfile` and the other person would `cat x* >newfile`. Then `newfile` will be a copy of `myfile`. This method can split any regular file (e.g. already compressed `myfile.zip`).

Comment: Well the problem is that the end users are most likely on Windows and they don't have access to of cat X*. So this method will be overkill for them.